# MS Access Error with DAO Recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

Am trying to create an empty DAO recordset rs2 whose structure is similar to an existing recordset rs1 (which has more than 200 fields). But I am facing an error which does not happen when I use ADO recordset:

```
dim rs2 as recordset

With rs2.Fields
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        .Append fld, adVariant
    Next
End With
```

Error is wrong number of arguments.

Comment: Are you missing some code? It does not look like `rs2` is instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

ADO allows you to add a field to the `Recordset.Fields` collection under certain circumstances.  That is why the ADO version of your code runs without error.

However, the DAO `Fields.Append` method can not be used with a `Recordset`.  Instead you would have to add a field to the table, or field expression to the query, which is used as the recordset's data source.

Comment: hello thanks for your reply. In that case, is there any way to do conversion between the recordsets?... I mean DAO to ADO?

Comment: I'm uncertain whether I understand the question.  It is not possible to create a DAO recordset object and then transform it to an ADO recordset.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this solution is not good for performance, but you can give it a try anyway.
First, clone the recordset:

```
Set rs2 = rs.clone
```

And then, if you only need the structure, empty it:

```
Do until rs2.EOF
    rs2.Delete
Loop
```

Comment: I think when you do rs2.delete, the records in rs actually gets deleted as well since both contains only the pointer to the actual location of the records

Comment: I don't know, but it could be as you say. At this point why not create a new table in SQL with the command DoCmd.RunSQL("SELECT * INTO RS2TABLE FROM RSTABLE WHERE FALSE") and open the dao recordset on the new table?

Comment: Hi..That's fine. But am looking for something simpler that that.:)...thanks you anyhow for ur replies...